# GWA TO HONOURS CLASS

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-kingdom, grades

In the Philippine Grading System, my GWA is **1.6250**, is there any chance to know the standing of this grade in the **UK GRADING SYSTEM**?

Comment: Sorry, but as I explained in the comment under your previous post, this question is essentially a duplicate. We cannot answer for each individual value of the GWA/GPA etc.